# Replace symbols in a string to tabs

Tags: ruby, string

How do I parse a string and change all the "a" letters to a tab symbol?

Is there a way to use a gsub for that?

something like

```
'blah'.gsub('a', '\t')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quoted (`"`) strings at least of the replacement that holds the tab:

```
'blah'.gsub('a', "\t")
#=> "bl\th"
```

Have a look at [Ruby Programming/Strings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes) for a very concise yet comprehensive overview of the differences between single and double quoted strings.

Comment: yeah, so I figured, could you explain why only doublt quotes work, please?

Comment: @JustMichael: In Ruby, `'\t'` does not mean *tab*, it means *backslash t* (two characters). The backslash only has a special meaning in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
'matador'.tr('a', "\t")
  #=> "m\tt\tdor"
```

You could write `?\t` in place of `"\t"`.